# Change date to display correctly

Tags: php, mysql, date

There are many date posts here, but i don't see one that helps me.

My mySQL field is in the format of yyyymmdd  (example:  20110423).

I need to display it properly on the page like:  04/23/2011

How do I go about doing that? I pull the data fine into the page as 20110423, but don't know how to reformat it when displaying it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Nick

Comment: Is the column a date / time type?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('r',strtotime('20110423'));
```

.. so in your case

```
echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime('20110423'));
```

Answer (score 2):

date_format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_out ...
```

Comment: since its the mysql date format, i think its a good guess that it is col date type.

Comment: your completely correct, the op looks to be using the wrong field type

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20110423');
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
```

The reason I like this better than `strtotime()` is that *it* can be picky about the date format given and you have no say over how it parses the string.

For example, given the date `12/10/2011` it will *always* parse this as "10th December, 2011". Change the slashes to hyphens `12-10-2011` and it becomes "12th October 2011".

*Disclaimer:* PHP 5.3+ only. As the 5.2 branch has ceased development and 5.3 has been around for almost two years, I don't see this as a problem.

**Edit:** If you don't have PHP 5.3 and the DB column is not a date type, you can use this extension on [Dagon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643034/change-date-to-display-correctly/5643043#5643043)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%Y%m%d'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS date_field ...
```

See [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: I would add that this is only available in PHP 5.3 and above, which many systems don't have available.